# Functionality in ydn.db is missing

Tags: ydn-db

I'm using `ydn.db-is-core-qry.js`, downloaded last week.

A lot of the functionality listed in the documentation is missing under the object `ydn.db`.
I cannot for instance find `ydn.db. KeyIterator` or `ydn.db. ValueIterator`. I've attached a screenshot from Firefox.

[Screenshot from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR1ch.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using compiled js file that has cursor module. See detail in its download page.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see where I can download the compiled js. Does this require a premium subscription?

Comment: ydn.db-isw-core-e-cur-qry-dev-raw.js is available without subscription.